# Unit test: Stub the file system layer in product code

Tags: python, unit-testing

Let's say that we have these code:

```
def judgement():
    content = _get_config_content()
    # do something in content
    return content + '.'


def _get_config_content():
    with open('test_config', 'r') as f:
        return f.read()
```

I want to test the `judgement` function, as we can see it: the judgement function is calling `_get_config_content()`, which is aimed to be private, and the `_get_config_content()` will open file and read it.

And it's good to stub out the file reading part, and there are two ways to stub the file reading logic:

1. stub private `_get_config_content()` function, and make it just return fake result.
2. stub the built-in `open` function, and make it return the fake file object.

Which way is better?  Or is there other way to stub the file system in unit test?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend in this case to stub `_get_config_content()`: a) It is simpler, because you only have to stub one function.  b) You don't lose much since there is not much value in unit-testing `_get_config_content()`: That function should rather be tested in integration testing anyway.